# How to make vertical pagination with display per page between arrow button

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have to implement pagination for my homework using jQuery. I have the button but cant get it work so far.

Here is the pagination button design

http://www.screencast.com/t/mKIlGPt3dFR

I need to outputing display per page (20/400) like in the button

Thanks,

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Putting total amount of displaying item. Let said i have 100 list item, with container only allowing 10 item to show. By default the item will showing from 1 - 10, so it will be 10/100 count. Let said i click next it will show item from 11-20, so the count should be update to be 20/100 and so on...something like that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mVcAL/5/#&togetherjs=q4dFDk6erq here is fidle with standard html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that (only for first part and reducing number):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#down').click(function(){
        var value = parseInt( $('#lower').text() );
        value -= 10;
        $('#lower').text(value);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVcAL/16/ modified your jsfiddle